# Динамическая высота у textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всю голову сломал, делаю следующее: копирую текстовый контент в модальное окно-форму в textarea. Необходимо авто-изменение высоты textarea без события на самом textarea, т. е. закидываю текст в textarea, и он автоматом меняет высоту в зависимости от контента в нём.

Answer (score 4):

Всё равно ничего лучше не придумаешь:

```js
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  e.target.style.height = 'auto'
  e.target.style.height = e.target.scrollHeight + 2 + "px"
})
```

```css
textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: none;
  min-height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Если требуется, чтобы она ещё под начальный текст приняла нужный размер, то можно явно вызвать соответствующую функцию:

```js
function fixTextareaSize(textarea) {
  textarea.style.height = 'auto'
  textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + 2 + "px"
}

~function () {
  var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea')
  textarea.addEventListener('input', function (e) { fixTextareaSize(e.target) })
  fixTextareaSize(textarea)
}()
```

```css
textarea {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  resize: none;
  min-height: 3em;
}
```

```html
<textarea>Всю голову сломал, делаю следующее, копирую текстовый контент в модальное окно-форму в textarea, необходимо авто-изменение высоты textarea БЕЗ СОБЫТИЯ НА САМОМ textarea, т.е. закидываю текст в textarea и он автоматом меняет высоту в зависимости от контента в нём.</textarea>
```